# Find $\alpha, \beta$ such that $\|v\| = \|(I - \alpha xx^\top -\beta yy^\top)v\|$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Let $x, y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be two distinct **unit vectors** and $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Define the vector
$$
w = (I - \alpha xx^\top -\beta yy^\top)v
$$
for some reals $\alpha, \beta\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\alpha, \beta\neq 0$.

> What non-zero values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ give $\|w\| = \|v\|$?

## Bonus

Suppose $x_1, \ldots, x_m$ are unit vectors and $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_m$are  non-zero scalars. What settings of these scalars would give
$$
(I - \sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i x_ix_i^\top)v
$$
the same norm as $v$?

Comment: When $m=1$ of course $\alpha=2$

Comment: When $m=2$ i suppose one needs to have $\alpha$ and $\beta$ depend on the “overlap” between $x$ and $y$, so perhaps they will depend on $x^\top y$

Comment: Probably makes more sense to stipulate that $x,y$ are linearly independent?

Answer (score 2):

If $A = I-\alpha xx^T-\beta yy^T,$ then clearly $A^T = A.$ Your requirement is the same as:
$$w^Tw = (Av)^T(Av) = v^TA^TAv = v^TA^2v = v^Tv.$$

This means $A^2$ must be an orthogonal matrix (preserving length implies orthogonal.) Therefore:
$$I = (A^2)(A^2)^T = A^4.$$
You can reverse this argument to say that if $A^4 = I,$ then $A^2$ is orthogonal  which then implies $w^Tw = v^Tv$ using symmetry. This means that as long as you pick $\alpha, \beta$ as the solutions of the equation:
$$A^4 = I$$
given $x,y$, it works. I am not sure if this yields an easy equation to solve though.

For example, if $x^Ty = 0,$ then the above equation will be simplified to:
$$\alpha(\alpha-2)(\alpha^2-2\alpha-2)xx^T + \beta(\beta-2)(\beta^2-2\beta-2)yy^T = 0$$
which gives $16$ ordered pairs of solutions. But $x^Ty\neq 0,$ then the equation does not get as simple.